# MQ Message rollback

Tags: java, jms, mq

I'm trying to read messages from an MQ queue in Java and I'm a little confused about the flow when comes time to roll back when handling exceptions.

I have a reader class that runs in a loop and look for message. When I initialize the reader, it creates a connection and a session. Then when comes time to read a message in the loop, it creates an `MQQueue` and `MQQueueReceiver`. This works fine and I get a JMSMessage out of the queue, which is then handed to another thread for work. If the worker thread fails, I want to put that message back onto the queue (so it gets retried by other nodes in my cluster).

My question is, how do I roll back? I noticed there's a `rollback()` method in the `MQQueueSession` class. But I'm reusing the same session for all my messages. Am I to understand that a new session should be created for each message instead of reusing the same one over and over?

This is counter intuitive to me.

Also the session is created with `connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);`. Should I use another flag, other than `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED flag and Session.commit/Sessiuon.rollback to commit/rollback all messages done in the current transaction

Answer (score 1):

Note that the JMS 1.1 spec defines session as:

> Session - a single-threaded context for sending and receiving messages

Later on in the spec it says:

> There are two reasons for restricting concurrent access to Sessions.
>   First, Sessions are the JMS entity that supports transactions. It is
>   very difficult to implement transactions that are multithreaded.
>   Second, Sessions support asynchronous message consumption. It is
>   important that JMS not require that client code used for asynchronous
>   message consumption be capable of handling multiple, concurrent
>   messages. In addition, if a Session has been set up with multiple,
>   asynchronous consumers, it is important that the client is not forced
>   to handle the case where these separate consumers are concurrently
>   executing. These restrictions make JMS easier to use for typical
>   clients. More sophisticated clients can get the concurrency they
>   desire by using multiple sessions.

So, no, you do not need one session per message.  However, all messages produced or consumed under a session are committed or rolled back together, *even if you've handed them off to other threads* and this behavior is per the spec.

Use the transacted session and COMMIT/ROLLBACK as described by Evgeniy but also take care to keep messages in the same session scope all within the same unit of work.